# error "no module named jplephem.pck" when trying to use skyfield

Tags: python, skyfield

I was trying to work with skyfield and I got the error that:
"ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'jplephem.pck'"
I get the error in the first line itself 
it goes like this:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ModuleNotFoundError                       Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-6-3a2b53f77cba> in <module>
----> 1 from skyfield.api import load
      2 
      3 planets = load('de421.bsp')
      4 earth, mars = planets['earth'], planets['mars']
      5 

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\skyfield\api.py in <module>
     12 from .errors import DeprecationError
     13 from .iokit import Loader, load_file
---> 14 from .planetarylib import PlanetaryConstants
     15 from .positionlib import position_from_radec
     16 from .starlib import Star

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\skyfield\planetarylib.py in <module>
      3 import re
      4 from numpy import array, cos, einsum, nan, rollaxis, sin
----> 5 from jplephem.pck import DAF, PCK
      6 from .constants import ASEC2RAD, AU_KM, DAY_S, tau
      7 from .functions import rot_x, rot_y, rot_z

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'jplephem.pck'
```

I tried to look it up on the net and it said that it is a dependency and I do not know what to do to debug this

```
from skyfield.api import load

planets = load('de421.bsp')
earth, mars = planets['earth'], planets['mars']

ts = load.timescale()
t = ts.now()
position = earth.at(t).observe(mars)
ra, dec, distance = position.radec()

print(ra)
print(dec)
print(distance)
```

Any form of help will be appreciated

Answer (score 0):

Did you install Skyfield with `pip install skyfield`, or through another mechanism? Current versions of Skyfield have a `setup.py` that insists on a recent version of `jplephem` because only versions more recent than 2.11 will have the `pck` module that Skyfield needs. The `pip` install tool should have detected this, but if it did not, doing `pip install -U jplephem` to force an update of `jplephem` should get you going again!

**Workaround**

If you are using `conda`, you will be installing an old version. Try:

```
conda uninstall jplephem
pip install -U jplephem
```

**Real solution**

The long-term solution is for the conda folks to get their packaging of this library working again. The list of pull requests on their "feedstock" for the library looks like it has encountered repeated failures to build and distribute an up-to-date package:

[image]

But the most recent PR is hand-written and has asked for moderator attention, so hopefully things will get fixed.

Comment: Anaconda only has jplephem up to 2.9, so conda users have to `conda uninstall jplephem`, (which uninstalls skyfield) then `pip install jplephem skyfield`